# How should I group similar exceptions in a docstring?

Tags: python, docstring

I don't see it mentioned in any style guide. Should I combine similar exception types or split them into separate lines:

```
"""
This is a Google style docs.
...
...
Raises:
    TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument. Key must be a numeric value.
    KeyError: bar
"""
```

or this:

```
"""
This is a Google style docs.
...
...
Raises:
    TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument
    TypeError: key must be a numeric value
    KeyError: bar
"""
```

Comment: have you read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/ ?

Comment: I would prefer the second one, will keep the docstring more readable. If the same error is raised for more than 2 reasons, will keep the lines shorter as well.

Comment: @VivekSable That doesn't mention anything about what OP is trying to do, does it?

Comment: what about the second option, but with `TypeError:` removed from the second line -- so second line starts with `key`, indented to be right under `foo`.

Comment: @Eyeofpie i don't know that there's an official python convention for this.  if i were you, i'd look at how a major package (e.g., numpy) is doing it, and copy them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think go with second.

```
"""
This is a Google style docs.
...
...
Raises:
    TypeError: 1. foo() missing 1 required positional argument.
               2. key must be a numeric value.
               3. ...
    KeyError:  1. bar key is missing.
               2. ...
"""
```

Comment: @dbliss: ok. may be. I read your comment after posting answer. You can add your answer I will Up-vote.